# Use ValidationMessageFor only required, ValidationSummary for everything else

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

With ASP.Net MVC 4, is it possible to use ValidationMessage() to display only the "*" for required fields and use ValidationSummary() to display all of the validation messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ValidationMessage overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504927%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("propName", "*")
```

And to display field errors, use the overloaded [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839469%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that display * for any validation message? I just want to use the * for required, if another validation attribute triggers a validation error (i.e. StringLength), I want those messages display via ValidationSummary().